# Найти телефонные номера в имеющемся листе | python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется лист вида:

`['Список клиентов и задач от 09 апреля 2020 г.', '№ клиента', 'Ник клиента', 'ФИО и Контакты', 'Менеджер клиента', 'Статус клиента', 'Дата', 'Менеджер задачи', 'Действие', 'Итог', 'Задача', 14872, 'Текст', 'ТЕКСТ Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; АЛЕКСАНДР ПЕРЕЗВОНИТЬ +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; АЛЕКСАНДР ПЕРЕЗВОН +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX', 'Фамилия Имя Отчество']`

Необходимо извлечь номера телефонов вида +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX, преобразовать их в вид XXXXXXXXXXX - то есть убрать "+", "(", ")", "-".
Прошу заметить, что в элементах списка есть повторение номеров: 'ТЕКСТ Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; ...'

регулярка: `r"\+[7-8]\([0-9]+\)[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+"`

Comment: Это вы нам задание дали?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вам надо, какую-то регулярку Вы написали. Дальше что?

Comment: Извините за тупые вопросы:
Не понимаю, как разбить вот эти элементы листа, типа таких: `"ТЕКСТ Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; Александр +X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX; ...'`, игнорировать всё остальное и добавить _только_ номера в отдельный лист.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, разобрался!

```
for i in l:
    tel = str(i)
    tel2 = (re.findall('\+([7-8]\([0-9]+\)[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)', tel))
    if tel2:
        l2.append(tel2)
```

Добавил все номера в отдельный список,

Получилось что-то такое:

`[['X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX, 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX'], ['X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX'], ...`

Затем:

```
for x in l2:
  for y in x:
    l4.append(y)
```

Наверное, можно было как-то проще сделать и менее коряво.